# RowSelected Exception

Tags: acumatica

Why does this code throw an exception on one system but not another?  The database on the working system is a restore backup of the non-working system.

```
var ext = PXCache<S.INItemSite>.GetExtension<S.INItemSiteExt>(row);
ext.UsrVendorLastCost = pvi.LastPrice;
```

Also, how can I use this query in PXFormula?

```
POVendorInventory pvi = PXSelect<POVendorInventory,
                                 Where<POVendorInventory.inventoryID, 
                                 Equal<Required<POVendorInventory.inventoryID>>>>
                                 .Select(new PXGraph(), row.InventoryID);
```

Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Screen: IN508000
When: The exception is thrown when I select a warehouse.

Stack Trace:

```
5/4/2018 7:37:28 AM Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

at PX.Objects.IN.INReplenishmentCreate_Extension.INReplenishmentItem_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e) in G:\projects\mind-over-software\Automatica\Projects\MillerEast\WebSite\App_Data\Projects\ReplenishmentCustomizations\ReplenishmentCustomizations\INReplenishmentCreate.cs:line 21 
at PX.Data.PXRowSelected.Invoke(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e) 
at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelected(Object item) 
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.set_Current(Object value) 
at PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) 
at PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) 
at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments) 
at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments) 
at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments swarguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() 
at PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.PX.Web.UI.IPXDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBoundInternal() 
at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.a(Dictionary`2 A_0, List`1 A_1) 
at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.a(PXCallbackResultMethod A_0, XmlWriter A_1) 
at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.a(PXCallbackResultMethod A_0)`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: can you include the stack trace found in the trace window after getting the exception? this will at least narrow down the line cuainsg the issues. My guess without having any more detail row or pvi objects are null. Also, for the 2nd question on formula you will need to indicate which field of POVendorInventory  you want to use. Is it last price?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get LastPrice.

Comment: Is PXFormula the correct attribute to be using?

Comment: @SimonML: Any ideas?